# Deploy Angular files to Azure StorageAccount - Failed to load resource:

Tags: angular, azure-pipelines-yaml, azcopy, azure-storage-account

I have deployed Angular dist files to a `Container` named `myui` in `Azure StorageAccount` using Azure Copy. The deployment was successful and the files are available in the `Container`.

Using the Blob url `https://uistorage.blob.core.windows.net/myui/index.html`the page opens but contents are missing. In Developer Tool (F12) I see ==> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.) as shown in the image below.

[image]

All the file items shown as Console Errors are available in the `container`,  but the url for those files show (on hover) as below `https://uistorage.blob.core.windows.net/styles.9993ca6d5497bdedc285.css` and does not seem to be right. Opening this url in the browser says as below.

> <Error> <Code>OutOfRangeInput</Code> <Message>One of the request
> inputs is out of range. RequestId:0ca3c3e5-f01e-0014-79d2-6d3d8e000000
> Time:2021-06-30T17:05:12.9184590Z</Message> </Error>

if the above url is changed to include the `Container` name `myui` like [https://uistorage.blob.core.windows.net/`myui`/styles.9993ca6d5497bdedc285.css](https://uistorage.blob.core.windows.net/%60myui%60/styles.9993ca6d5497bdedc285.css) then that file opens in the browser

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 options to address this problem
One solution was to add `"build": "ng build --base-href=/path"` in `package.json`

Another approach was that, we moved to place the angular app to App Service instead of a Container which was more suitable for our app.